# How to change console logging in production with Spring in log4j2?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

How can I disable console logging completely in production? (eg using `spring.profiles.active=production`?

During dev I always want to see the full console logging. But in production I'd like to prevent console out. But how?

log4j2-spring.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="XML"  .../>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
       <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="XML" />
       </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

Sidenote: the INFO statements should still be logged to XML file. They should just not be printed to console additionally.

Comment: create two other files one for each environment and include it in you main file like this  `<include resource="log4j2-${spring.profiles.active}.xml"/>`. In prod file use only one appender and in dev use two appenders

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using vm args as follows:

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
       <property name="console.log">INFO</property> <!-- default value if not set -->
    </Properties>

        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="${sys:console.log}" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </Console>
```

The logger will use `INFO` level by default. And when providing eg `-Dconsole.log=ERROR` on launch, it will only log errors to console.

Would be even nicer if log4j2 could read just a property defined in `application-production.properties`, but for not the approach works.

Comment: You should be able to use `<ThresholdFilter level="${sys:console.log:-INFO}" .../>` to set the default value as an alternative to creating a property for it